# How to Silence Commands Being Broadcast?

Tags: sound

Whenever I enter any command on my computer, it has started broadcasting those commands via audio. It keeps announcing. This is terribly annoying. How do I switch this off? (Don't know how it got activated!!) What command should I use to switch it off? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have inadvertently turned on `Screen Reader`.

Go to `System Settings` -> `Univalsal Access` -> Click the `Screen Reader` `On/Off` switch to off.

You can also use the Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>